# Best way to format date in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my example data using SQL Server with `date` type

```
TglUnggah = 30/03/2014
```

I need date format 'dd/MM/yyyy'

My stored procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_ViewFile] 
AS 
BEGIN   
   SELECT        
      IdFile, IdAkses, NamaFile, Count, 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TglUnggah, 103) AS TglUnggah, 
      Keterangan, Role, Url     
   FROM            
      tbFile 
END
```

When running this stored procedure in ASP.NET, the data is `30/03/2014`, but in detailview the format changes to `30/03/2014 0:00:00` and can't been updated

What is the best way to use format `dd/MM/yyyy` in SQL Server / stored procedure / ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. Use DateTime whenever possible. Only convert to a formatted string when you need to display output to the user. At that point, you should use whatever format is appropriate for that user's culture.

DateTime has the advantage that it's easy to do manipulations with and you don't have to worry about converting formats everywhere. DateTime is actually a wrapper around the number of ticks since a specific date (you don't need to know that), so there is no inherent string representation of a DateTime object (you do need to know that).

Comment: @Ehsan The question appears to be about how to format the date for using in various places, and that's what I answered. If that's not the case, the OP is perfectly capable of clarifying themself.

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in SQl server you can use [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this procedure:

```
       public static string ConvertDtFormat(string dateTimeString)
       {
           dateTimeString = dateTimeString.Trim();
           while (dateTimeString.Contains("  "))
           {
               dateTimeString = dateTimeString.Replace("  ", " ");
           }

           if (dateTimeString == null || dateTimeString.Length == 0)
           {
               return string.Empty;
           }
           else
           {
               DateTime convertedDateTime = new DateTime();
               string userDateFormat = HMS.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT;

               try
               {
                   if (userDateFormat.Trim().Contains("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                       convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, format_dmy, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                               DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);
                   else if (userDateFormat.Trim().Contains("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                       convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, format_mdy, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                               DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);

                   return convertedDateTime.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt");
               }
               catch
               {
                   return "Invalid DateTime";
               }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to consider.  When globalising you may need to deal with different time zones so you may want to store dates with date time offset allowing you store UTC times.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is who want to show date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' in the whole application and no timezone related used. Otherwise, you need to convert /cast the data to show.

The best thing for this issue to solve is :- written at the before to date operation done

```
Set Dateformat DMY
```

**Basic rule to understand about dateformat :-**

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/28/sql-server-introduction-and-example-for-dateformat-command/

Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME
(
     parameter...
)
as

BEGIN
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

OTHER STATEMENT
END
```

You can test as

```
Set Dateformat dmy

Declare @date datetime = '10-06-2012'

select @date
```

Its simply convert your datetime format as you need

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189491.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1740263.aspx?SET+DATEFORMAT+dmy+SELECT+FROM+Table1+WHERE+Type+ee+order+by+cast+Date+as+datetime+desc